# Find last digits with IF

Tags: excel

I have lots of cells in the spreadsheet that contains the whole year, date and stock prices, but I only need the dates from 25th of the last month till the 5th of this month.How can I write a function to do that?  For example if the cells are like this in the column:

```
19900101  
19900102 
19900103
19900104
19900105 
.  
.  
19900125
19900126  
19900127  
19900128
19900129
19900130
19900131
```

I want it to show only days `(1,2,3,4,5,25,26,27,28,29,30,31)` with the date format.
The date shows in the text format and I've tried format cell to change it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: January doesn't have its 31st day in your data?

Comment: Please edit your question so your example does not contradict the first paragraph (first and last 5 or 2 days?).

Comment: @Andrew,well Andrew although the question wants only 5 days in first and last but the formula that xQbert write shows the date 25 from the last month till the 5th of this month.which was i need so i change the question as you want:)

Comment: @pnuts,thanks for the edit,no i dont want UDF,i prefered after it find the data with formula it can put it in another spreadsheet with out the empty rows,but it seems too much work for excel:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a slightly different approach, assuming you want to return the A2 value only if it represents a date in the **last 5** or **first 5** days of any month you can use this formula in `B2`

`=IF(DAY(TEXT(A2,"0000-00-00")+5)<11,A2,"")`

`TEXT` function converts your data to a real date then if you add 5 days to that date then any date that was originally in the last 5 or first 5 of the month will now be in the first 10 days of the month.....so it's sufficient to check that the day is < 11. That will pick up 27th to 31st of a 31 day month, 26th to 30th of a 30 day month etc.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a formula and then filter by rows with data...
As an example (given it's difficult to discern if you always want the first 5 and last 5 of a month or what....)

`=IF(RIGHT(A2,2)*1<=2,A2,IF(RIGHT(A2,2)*1>=29,A2,""))`

[image]

Comment: What about February? o.O

Comment: @sali, if your data is not missing any day, you can use this formula instead, which will work regardless of the amount of days of the month: `=IF(OR(A7-A2>5,MOD(A2,100)<=5),A2,"")`. It will *select* January from 27th to 31st and February from 24th to 28th. This only works if the data is numeric and not string. If it's string, you will have to use the functions xQbert used.

Comment: this is the new answer for edited question(based on xQbert answer) IF(RIGHT(A2,2)*1<=5,A2,IF(RIGHT(A2,2)*1>=25,A2,""))

Comment: I have another question,How can i change this kind of date format to the normal one?like 1990/01/01.thanks in advance

Comment: @pnuts, why hardcode a 26 there? It's better to have a solution for any month. Anyway, after the edits, it seems showing >25 is enough...

Comment: @sali, if you want that format, use this formula: `=IF(OR(A7-A2>5,MOD(A2,100)<=5),LEFT(A2,4)&"/"&MID(A2,5,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A2;2),"")`. It's the same I commented above, but I replaced the last `A2` with the concatenation of the date parts, which I get by using `LEFT`, `MID` and `RIGHT`.

Comment: @Andrew its a good idea but I want excel realize that this is the date format so i can filter it by year. I've tried cell format but it doesn't works.

Comment: It would be great if you specify all your requirements at once, so we don't have to continually modify the proposed solution! I added a separate answer with my formula.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the edits and comments, these should be the function you need.

```
=IF(OR(A7-A2>5,MOD(A2,100)<=5),DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,5,2),RIGHT(A2,2)),"")
```

You should place it in cell `B2` and then do all the desired filtering, as explained in xQbert's answer.